# New bootstrap form to be displayed on click of a button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dynamicform

I have a bootstrap button. When that button is clicked, I need to display a form or a text area just below the button.

If there were any components below the button before the button was clicked, then they should be moved below the new form/text area that is to be displayed.

Could you please guide me on how to implement this in bootstrap?

Comment: What you have tried so far? or it would be better if you share your html also

Comment: You can use bootstrap's `Collapse` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Bootstrap 4](http://getbootstrap.com/) to achieve this.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-
</button>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

Or you can use jQuery

`$( "#button" ).append( "<form>Your form</form>" );`

Bootstrap also uses jQuery under the hood. Using the first option can toggle the form while the second one would keep adding the form.

Comment: Hi Soh Jun, I tried your sample and got both the button and form displayed in parallel. I would like to display the form only when the button is clicked.